# Why is my Ajax request failing for infinity scroll pagination in laravel?

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, jquery-pagination, laravel-pagination

I am trying to perform an infinity scroll pagination using window.scroll() method on laravel. Whenever I reach bottom of the page-

1. loadMoreData(page) is called.
2. beforeSend:function() successfully executes.
3. .fail() calls from $.ajax() and alerts "server not responding".

Here are my laravel and ajax codes below from 3 different files - index.blade, data.blade(Views/data), PostController.php

**INDEX.BLADE**

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')

`<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">`

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"integrity="sha2569/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0="crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">



<div class="col-md-12" id="post-data">
    @include('data')
  </div>

  <div class="ajax-load text-center" style ="display:none">
    <p><img src="/storage/Rand_Img/insta-dataloader.gif">Loading More Post... </p>
  </div>

</div>

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){


  function loadMoreData(page){
     $.ajax({
       url:'?page='+ page,
       type:'get',
       beforeSend:function(){
         $(".ajax-load").show();
       }
     }).done(function(data){
       if(data.html == " "){
         $('.ajax-load').html("No more data");
       }
       $('.ajax-load').hide();
       $("#post-data").append(data.html);
     }).fail(function(jqXHR, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
       alert('Server not responding!');
console.log("textStatus: "+textStatus+"\n ajaxOPtions: "+ajaxOptions+"\n jqXHR: "+jqXHR);
     });
   }


$(window).scroll(function(){
  var page = 1;
if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(document).height() ){
 page++;
 loadMoreData(page);
}
  });


});

</script>

@endsection
```

**Data.BLADE**

```
 <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0="
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


 @foreach ($post as $show)

  <div class="row">

     <div class="col-6 offset-1">
        <div class="">
          <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
            <div class="pr-4">
              <img src="{{$show->user->Profile->profileImage() }}"
               alt="{{$show->image}}" style="width:70px;" class="rounded-circle">
            </div>
           <a href="/profile/{{$show->user->id}}/index" style=" font-size:20px;">
             {{$show->user->username}}</a>
             <a href="#" style=" font-size:20px;" class="pl-4">Follow</a>
          </div>

          <div class="">
          <p style="font-size:20px;" class="p-4">{{$show->caption}}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row pb-5 ">
    <div class="col-6 offset-3">
    <a href="/profile/{{$show->user->id}}/index">
      <img src="/storage/{{$show->image}}" alt="{{$show->image}}"class="w-100"></a>
    </div>
  </div>

@endforeach
```

**PostController.php**

```
 $user_id = auth()->user()->following()->pluck('profiles.user_id');

 $post = Post::whereIn('user_id', $user_id)->orderBy('created_at','DESC')->Paginate(3);


 if(($request->ajax())){
   $view  = view('data', compact('post'))->render();
   return response()->json(['html'=>$view]);

 }
   return view('Post/index', compact('post'));
```

**This is what I am getting from network tab...**

[image]

**Response:**

[image]

Comment: Please share more details - is there anything written to the applications error log?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to put the full URL into your ajax call method?
I believe that without specifying the full URL like you did `url:'?page='+ page`, jQuery will use the current browser page URL as base URL. So Something like `url:'https://example.com?page='+ page`.

EDIT:
Your controller seems to return when the request is Ajax `response()->json(['html'=>$view]);`. What is the `$view` object, and why returning it? You should only return the `$post` variable as JSON, and also retrieve the page number from the request URL parameters (hardcoded at 3 in your script).

Comment: Ya i just used 
`url:'http://127.0.0.1:8000/?page='+ page`

Still fails!

I'm using Sqlite btw hope that isnt the issue

Comment: `http://127.0.0.1:8000` is the URL for "live building", after `yarn run start` for example, no? Your laravel application should have its proper URL. Do you need to run a command to make this URL work? What are you using as a local environment?

Comment: I am basically using php artisan from the project folder using command prompt to run this application if thats what you wanna know..

Comment: Hum, so you don't have any webserver running? Like WAMP or Laragon? You should have a webserver pointing to the /public folder of your Laravel application. Is any API route working when querying http://127.0.0.1:8000? As this URL is from a webserver spawn by artisan (I guess) for frontend development purposes mostly. Can you check in your browser network console tab, what is the full URL jquery is trying to reach?

Comment: Well I have Xampp installed but apparently I am not running on Xampp, as i said just `php artisan serve` command using CMD prompt.

For api route I guess you're talking about my `web.php` which is - `Route::get('/', [App\Http\Controllers\PostController::class, 'index']);` .

The network console tab continuously loads `?page=2`. When clicked on one of the links this is shown:
**Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/?page=2
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:8000
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin**

Comment: Ah, so it's not a URL error directly, but more a CORS issue. I really think you should handle API requests with your XAMPP, not with the server spawned by Artisan. Can you try make your xampp operationnal with a vhost pointing on the /public directory of your app? So in the end: make your laravel work with your xampp, and make API request to the xampp webserver. It'll be mluch more complex to handle CORS with the artisan spawned server.

Comment: so now I am using vhost from Xampp, but the problem is still there!!
However i noticed something before as well, the console tab for browser shows 5 errors and this happens only if there's ajax codes in that page.

I'll just post a small portion of the error here in case you think its an issue:

Comment: `app.js:38457 [Vue warn]: Error compiling template:

Templates should only be responsible for mapping the state to the UI. Avoid placing tags with side-effects in your templates, such as <script>, as they will not be parsed.

49 |              
50 |  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
51 |  

   |  `

Comment: What is the full URL you setted in your request script? And does it respond using postman? The other error seems not related, but may prevent the build and so prevent testing your new code. Add console.log to be sure that the new version is built and in use when testing. Or of course, the same error will append as the code not changed in your browser.

Comment: `url:'http://freeCodeGram.com/?page='+ page,` this is my URL request, I had set vhost under freeCodeGram.com

Comment: ok so this how I am outputting console.Log: `.fail(function(jqXHR, ajaxOptions,textStatus, thrownError){        console.log(textStatus+"\n"+ajaxOptions+"\n"+jqXHR);      });`


 **OUTPUT :**
`SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 1` /


`parsererror` /


 `[object Object]` 
What do you think is the error here?

Comment: Well now it seems your server is answering something, but the JSON may be corrupted. Can you look at the network tab of your browser console to see what the server response contains?  Did you try quering your route with something else like Postman?

Comment: I just updated my question and posted an image of my network tab check that out

Comment: Click on a ?page request to see the response content

Comment: ya clicked, opens a new tab and load page 2 properly! Just doesnt load through pagination

Comment: No, you must see in the Chrome console the response of the request. Not open it in a new tab. If you click on the request name in the request table your screened, it should open a right pannel with some tabs, and one will give you the content of the XHR request. Thats what I want to see, as JS says that the JSON is malformed.

Comment: Yes exactly !! So you see, here you have your <script> tags coming BEFORE your json. But your JSON is here, just after. But as there is "characters" before your json, it's interpreted as malformed. So I think that you call the same route from your browser, and from your script? Cause your proper API route should not send back <script> that are HTML characters of course. But just the JSON.

Comment: Ah, in your script you do "json(['html'=>$view]);", but what is the $view? you should only return $post as JSON. If you want your route to return the full html of the page, it's another thing.

Comment: so how exactly do you want me to solve this issue?

Comment: As I said, why your method is returning the $view variable? and not the $post variable? Try to return the $post variable when its an ajax call. Also, you are using the same route to render your page HTML, and to handle your ajax queries. You should do 2 different route: one for the HTML/Blade, the other for the ajax request. But first, try in your existing code to return the $post variable, and use route parameter to get page number like so ->paginate((int)request()->input('page', 1))

Comment: ok i'll try..
but firstly I wanna make sure do I have to remove all the 3 <link> and <script> tags that are coming before my JSON data? Cuz u said **"here you have your <script> tags coming BEFORE your json. But your JSON is here, just after. But as there is "characters" before your json, it's interpreted as malformed."**

Comment: Well no. The best as I told you would be to have 2 route. If you only want 1 route to handle HTML page and ajax request (like you did), your ajax need to return only the "$post" variable as your JS only need the posts. Not the $view which contains some HTML.